# Anyone know of a .NET serialized class editor?

Tags: .net, class, serialization

So I was looking at Solar 2 in dotPeek, and I noticed the saved game files are in the format of raw serialized classes. Does anyone know of a program (preferably free) that can read this format and edit it?

Comment: The .NET framework itself? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz.aspx (The serialisation format might not really include any metadata about the original object structure beyond some guards to check for it having changed.)

Comment: StackOverflow is mostly for programming questions. Usually "where can I find a program to do that?" type of questions is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the original app dlls, just reference them and deserialize into its classes using whatever deserializer it is using.

If you do not have original classes and it is using `BinaryFormatter`, you will have to implement binary reader according to specification at [[MS-NRBF]: .NET Remoting: Binary Format Data Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try and see it they are plain [Serializable] objects and use the code below, however, if there is a custom serializer then you will need to get the semantics of that.

```
public static class Serializer
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the object to an XML string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="anObject">An object.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string SerializeObject(object anObject)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(anObject.GetType());
                System.IO.MemoryStream aMemStr = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(aMemStr, null);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, anObject);
                string strXml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(aMemStr.ToArray());
                return strXml;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static object DeSerializeObject(Type objectType, string aString)
        {
            object obj = null;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
                obj = xs.Deserialize(new StringReader(aString));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; 
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` just kill the stack for no reason?

Comment: You are right it should be Catch(){ throw; } This class did have logging at one time and the exception would have been logged. I moved it to a lower level with no logging and have not removed the catch(Exception) piece...thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SharpSerializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html)

Hope this works for you.